# Displaying modified live camera preview

Tags: android, android-camera

I've currently made an android app that can display a live preview of the camera, but I'm looking for a way to perform live pixel manipulation (ie, make the image grayscale, sepia-toned, etc.). As of yet I haven't found any code for someone whose done this before.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `Camera.Parameters` to set the appropriate effect. Read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html).

If you want to do the manipulation by yours then use `onPreviewFrame` of camera. This gives you raw `byte[]` of `YUV` format (its by default, you could set it to other formats also. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFormat%28int%29) for setting the preview format).

Now you could able to perform any pixel manipulation you want on `byte[]`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: And how to display the new image?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690898/drawing-to-a-surfaceview-in-android to learn how to draw.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846500/modify-live-camera-view/17037027#17037027). In short, this [tutorial](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tutorials/android_tutorial/get-started-with-opencv-on-android/) gives you probably the best way, how to achieve this (by using OpenCV, a free Computer Vision library). You can download their example application from their [website](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/code-example-module/opencv-code-example/) as well.