# Swift Get Every Frame From Camera and Modify With CIImage

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I have seen many tutorials that show how to place the live camera image on the screen, but I want to modify the images with a CIImage. I have taken a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIImagePickerController), but couldn't find out if that would work. I am assuming that to do this, I need to take every frame, modify it, and then put it on the screen. I would like something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846500/modify-live-camera-view/), but in Swift.
My questions are:

- How to set up a function that is called when a new captured is found by the camera
- How to modify the image **effectively**. (I already know how to use CIImage, but it is very laggy)

Comment: To handle more camera functions, you should use AVFoundation to show camera view. This camera session will return each captured frame through delegate function `captureOutput(_:didOutputSampleBuffer:from:)`. There's already an nice sample from Apple. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html

Comment: @PhucNguyen I did try to convert that code a while ago, but it did not work. Found a good question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475737/convert-uiimage-to-cmsamplebufferref#16487926) though. Going to check it out.

Comment: The link in the first comment leads to a 404 page.